# Pipeline processor vs. Single-cycle processor

Tags: cpu, pipeline, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture, mips32

I have to compare the speed of execution of the following code (see picture) using DLX-pipeline and single-cycle processor.

Given:
 
an instruction in the single-cycle model takes 800 ps
a stage in the pipeline model takes 200 ps (based on MA)

My approach was as follows.

> CPU time = CPI * CC * IC
>  
>   **Single-cycle:**
>  
>   CPU time = 1 * 800 ps * 10 instr. = 8000 ps.
>   **Pipeline:** 
>   CPI = 21 cycles / 10 instr. = 2.1 cycles per instruction
>   CPU time = 2.1 * 200 ps * 10 = 4200 ps.
>  
>   CPU time single-cycle / CPU time pipeline = 8000/4200 = 1.9, so **the pipeline code runs 1.9 faster.**

But I was said, I have to work with clock cycles and not with the time -- "It doesn't matter how much time a CC takes".

I don't see how to make a comparison otherwise. Could you please help me?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is indeed correct, but I guess your professor is looking for an explanation like this:

Suppose the single cycle processor also has the stages that you have mentioned, namely IF, ID, EX, MA and WB and that the instruction spends roughly the same time in each stage as compared to the pipelined processor version. Now you can draw a pipeline diagram for this single cycle processor, and see that it would take 50 cycles on a single cycle processor (which can work on 1 instruction at a time) compared to the 19 cycles on a pipelined processor.

Again, I prefer the way you have analyzed it (as the single cycle processor wouldn't really have each of those stages in a different clock cycle, it would just have a very long clock cycle to cover all the stages). Also, you've not mentioned whether this is a stalling-only MIPS pipeline (for which your answer is correct) or if this is a bypassed-MIPS pipeline. If this is the latter, you can shave off a few more cycles and get it down to 15 cycles.